# HTML5 Offline Manifest not working

Tags: offline

I have a jQuery Mobile app. It has an HTML manifest setup and I can see everything listed in the Application Cache that I have listed in the manifest. However when I turn off my internet connection its unable to load another page. Any ideas what might be causing this?

[image: application cache]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmkNE.png): [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had query string in my link to MobileContactDetail and the manifest doesn't work with query strings in in the URL unless it has a specific entry for it. I ended up reworking the app to be a true single page application.